# How to get mod value from variable and result

Tags: python, math, modular-arithmetic

```
variable v = 256478

modular m = 568742

result  r = 256478

v (mod) m = r , 256478 (mod) 568742 = 256478
```

**my question how to find mod (m = ?) value from variable and result (some case my program)**

```
v (mod) ? = r

256478 (mod) ? = 256478

262713 (mod) ? = 262713
```

here variable V and result r known need to find possible mod m = ? value

**condition is v = r  -->  variable and result always equal,then m = ?**

which value used to mod variable to get result, the result equal to variable

One of my program development I need this

Comment: Your examples are not very clear.  They seem to indicate any number larger than v will suffice.  Please provide a more robust range of samples so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is interesting to note that for all positive integers.

If variable  `v` and result `r` are equal then `m` must be **any value greater than `v`**.

Like:

`256478 (mod) 256479 = 256478`
`256478 (mod) 356479 = 256478`
`262713 (mod) 262714 = 262713`
`262713 (mod) 272714 = 262713`

http://ideone.com/8Pd4i8

Let me know if it helps: